# wpf - popoup won't close on IsMouseOver = False

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

I have a popup style declared as a resource.  I Have this popup open (using datatriggers) when the `PlacementTarget IsMouseOver = true` and when the popup itself `IsMouseOver = True`.  I added a trigger for when the popup `IsMouseOver = False` to close the popup. But it stays open unless the user clicks outside the popup. I want it to close when the mouse leaves the popup and is not over the placement target.

Here is my popup style:

```
<Style x:Key="FTC_PopupStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
    <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Slide"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**QUESTION:** Can someone help me adjust this so that the popup closes when the mouse leaves the target.

### EDIT:1

Okay,  SO this seems to be an issue that is common, but I could not find a solution that worked. I am wanting to implement a hover button.  When the user moves their mouse over a UI element that is the Placement Target for the popup a list of commands should appear. I can do this with a popup attached to a button.

*What I need* is for the popup to close when the mouse is not over it. I am willing to use code behind but the `mouseLeave` and `isMouseOverChanged` events only fire when the user clicks outside the popup, not when the mouse pointer moves out from directly over it. Also, the popup will not open again if I set it to `IsOpen=False` in the `MouseLeave` event. I am surprised this is such a difficult thing.

I think I might need to create a custom control for this.

### EDIT 2:

Here is a screen shot for clarity:
[image]

I want the popup to open when user hovers over the "JOB MANAGEMENT" Button. Then I want the popup to stay open if the user moves their mouse over the popup itself so they can click one of the buttons in the popup control.  But I want the popup to close if the mouse is not over the popup itself OR the JOB MANAGEMENT button.

Does anyone have any idea on how to force a popup closed when the mouse leaves it?  My ideal solution is something I can define within style in resource dictionary.

### EDIT 3:

Here is the XAML I used trying to bind the `isOpen` to a wrapping container as per Marc suggestion. It did not work:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="JobListPanel">
    <Button x:Name="SubJobList" Content="JO_B MANAGEMENT" Style="{StaticResource NavChildButton}" />
    <Popup x:Name="JobPopUp" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SubJobList}" Style="{StaticResource FTC_PopupStyle}"  >
        <Border Style="{StaticResource FTC_PopupBorder}" >
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <Button Content="Vie_w Jobs" Style="{StaticResource NavSubButton}"  />
                <Button Content="Add _New Job" Style="{StaticResource NavSubButton}"  />
                <Button Content="Job _Reports" Style="{StaticResource NavSubButton}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</StackPanel>

<Style x:Key="FTC_PopupStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Slide"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Those DataTrigger such big time my friend. What are you doing there?

Comment: @devhedgehog I'm Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: not sure if it would help, but in the DataTrigger Binding, have you tried to set UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"?

Comment: @NETscape, thanks, but that did not work

Comment: I would suggest making a custom control because you need to know the context and mouse state of both the of the controls at the same time.  The flickering you're seeing is the exact instant IsMouseOver on the Popup is false. In other words there will always be a small gap of time between PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver and Popup.IsMouseOver.  Make a control and override the OnMouseLeave and OnMouseEnter

Comment: @NETscape, what control would you base the custom control on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by creating a custom control (of type content control, with a border, button and popup in the template) and overriding the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events of the content control.

Here is the custom control class I used (vb.net ):

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Text

<TemplatePart(Name:="PART_TargetContentBorder", Type:=GetType(Border))> _
<TemplatePart(Name:="PART_MenuButton", Type:=GetType(Button))> _
<TemplatePart(Name:="PART_Popup", Type:=GetType(Popup))> _
Public Class HoverMenuButton
    Inherits ContentControl

#Region "DECLARATIONS"

    Private HoverPopUp As Popup
    Private TargetBorder As Border
    Private TargetButton As Button

#End Region

#Region "PROPERTIES"

#End Region

#Region "DEPENDENCY PROPERTIES "
    ''' <summary>
    ''' BORDER STYLE: The Style of the Border the wraps the Popup and PopUp's Target Placement Element
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property BorderStyle As Style
        Get
            Return GetValue(BorderStyleProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Style)
            SetValue(BorderStyleProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly BorderStyleProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
                        "BorderStyle", GetType(Style), GetType(HoverMenuButton), _
                        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender))

    ''' <summary>
    ''' POPUP STYLE: The Style of the Popup 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property PopUpStyle As Style
        Get
            Return GetValue(PopUpStyleProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Style)
            SetValue(PopUpStyleProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly PopUpStyleProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
                        "PopUpStyle", GetType(Style), GetType(HoverMenuButton), _
                        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender))

    ''' <summary>
    ''' BUTTON STYLE: The Style of the Button 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property ButtonStyle As Style
        Get
            Return GetValue(ButtonStyleProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Style)
            SetValue(ButtonStyleProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly ButtonStyleProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
                        "ButtonStyle", GetType(Style), GetType(HoverMenuButton), _
                        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender))

    ''' <summary>
    ''' BUTTON CONTENT: The Text of the Button
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property ButtonContent As String
        Get
            Return GetValue(ButtonContentProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly ButtonContentProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
                        "ButtonContent", GetType(String), GetType(HoverMenuButton), _
                        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender))

    ''' <summary>
    ''' BUTTON COMMAND: The iCommand of the button
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property ButtonComand As ICommand
        Get
            Return GetValue(ButtonComandProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ICommand)
            SetValue(ButtonComandProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly ButtonComandProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
                        "ButtonComand", GetType(ICommand), GetType(HoverMenuButton), _
                        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender))

    ''' <summary>
    ''' BUTTON COMMAND: The iCommand of the button
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property ButtonComandParameter As String
        Get
            Return GetValue(ButtonComandParameterProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            SetValue(ButtonComandParameterProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly ButtonComandParameterProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( _
                        "ButtonComandParameter", GetType(String), GetType(HoverMenuButton), _
                        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender))
#End Region

#Region "INITIALIZE CONTROLS"
    Private Sub InitializePopup()
        If HoverPopUp Is Nothing Then
            HoverPopUp = TryCast(Me.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", Me), Popup)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub InitializeTargetBorder()
        If TargetBorder Is Nothing Then
            TargetBorder = TryCast(Me.Template.FindName("PART_TargetContentBorder", Me), Border)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub InitializeTargetButton()
        If TargetButton Is Nothing Then
            TargetButton = TryCast(Me.Template.FindName("PART_MenuButton", Me), Button)
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "POPUP METHODS"
    Private Sub PopupOpen()
        If HoverPopUp IsNot Nothing Then
            HoverPopUp.IsOpen = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub PopupClose()
        If HoverPopUp IsNot Nothing AndAlso HoverPopUp.IsOpen = True Then
            HoverPopUp.IsOpen = False
        Else
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "CLASS METHODS"

#End Region

#Region "BASE CONTENT CONTROL EVENT HANDELRS"
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(e As MouseEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
        PopupClose()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(e As MouseEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
        PopupOpen()
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "APPLY TEMPLATE"
    Public Overrides Sub OnApplyTemplate()
        MyBase.OnApplyTemplate()

        '' if template is not nothing then initialize controls and wire up the event handlers
        If Me.Template IsNot Nothing Then

            InitializePopup()
            InitializeTargetBorder()
            InitializeTargetButton()

            ''Apply any styles / properties defined
            If TargetButton IsNot Nothing Then
                If ButtonStyle IsNot Nothing Then
                    TargetButton.Style = ButtonStyle
                End If
                If ButtonContent IsNot Nothing Then
                    TargetButton.Content = ButtonContent
                End If
                If ButtonComand IsNot Nothing Then
                    TargetButton.Command = ButtonComand
                    If ButtonComandParameter IsNot Nothing Then
                        TargetButton.CommandParameter = ButtonComandParameter
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            If HoverPopUp IsNot Nothing AndAlso PopUpStyle IsNot Nothing Then
                HoverPopUp.Style = PopUpStyle
            End If

            If TargetBorder IsNot Nothing AndAlso BorderStyle IsNot Nothing Then
                TargetBorder.Style = BorderStyle
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "CONSTRUCTOR"
    Shared Sub New()
        'This OverrideMetadata call tells the system that this element wants to provide a style that is different than its base class.
        'This style is defined in Themes\Generic.xaml
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(HoverMenuButton), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(HoverMenuButton)))
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Here is the xaml for the generic template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HoverMenuButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HoverMenuButton}">
                <Border x:Name="PART_ControlBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="PART_MenuButton" />
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_MenuButton}" >
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Popup> 
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It is defined in its own project, so here is how I used it in my wpf mvvm application:

```
<CustomControl:HoverMenuButton ButtonContent="Test" ButtonStyle="{StaticResource NavChildButton}">
                <Border Style="{StaticResource FTC_ButtonBorders}" >
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Button Content="Vie_w Jobs" Style="{StaticResource NavSubButton}" Command="{Binding NavigateSubCommand}" CommandParameter="jobview" ToolTip="Job Details" />
                        <Button Content="Add _New Job" Style="{StaticResource NavSubButton}" Command="{Binding NavigateSubCommand}" CommandParameter="jobadd" ToolTip="Add New Job" />
                        <Button Content="Job _Reports" Style="{StaticResource NavSubButton}" Command="{Binding NavigateSubCommand}" CommandParameter="jobreport" ToolTip="Display and Print Job Reports" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Border>
            </CustomControl:HoverMenuButton>
```

This creates the exact same layout as my screen shot, but now if the mouse enters the button text the popup opens, stays open if the mouse moves into the popup and closes automatically once the mouse leaves the popup and button text.

I hope this is useful to someone else

JK

Answer (score 2):

Remove this style

```
 <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="False"/>
```

Or make it `True`, and it will work.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) states:

> When the StaysOpen property is set to true, Popup stays open until it is explicitly closed by setting the IsOpen property to false. When StaysOpen is false, the Popup control intercepts all mouse and keyboard events to determine when one of these events occurs outside the Popup control.

Here you want to control the popup behavior by setting `IsOpen` property yourself. Hence, you need to set `StaysOpen` to `True`.

Comment: thanks, this causes the popup to close automatically when the user's mouse leaves the PlacementTarget element.  But I want it to stay open if the user's mouse enters the popup itself.  See my edit and screen shot for clarity. This does not solve my problem yet.

Comment: Ok, This will work if you don't leave any space between the `PlacementTarget` and `Popup`. If there is space between, when the user moves from `PlacementTarget` to `Popup`, It will close as there will be a moment when mouse is not on top of either of them.

Comment: Can you tell me if you have empty space(margin or something) between `Popup` and the `PlacementTarget`?

Comment: I don't think I do.  I  manually set all margin and padding for all elements to zero,  but the popup flickers but does not stay open when the mouse moves over it.  I will double check.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the `Popup` and its `PlacementTarget` together in a container? In that case you can bind `IsOpen` to `IsMouseOver` of that container as a `RelativeSource` and it will work seamlessly.

Comment: tried that, wrapped them both in a border and then used the border as the placement target.  Exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: No, use `PlacementTarget` as old one itself, just change the source of `IsMouseOver` binding to the container.

Comment: Tried it and it did not work.  I edited my post to include the code I tried as per your suggestion.  I think I am left with creating a custom control.

Answer (score 1):

I know you wrote a custom control and all, but maybe this will help someone.

```
  <Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
      <TextBlock x:Name="JobManagement" Text="Job Management" 
               Foreground="LightGray" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave" />

      <Popup x:Name="JobManagementMenu" Placement="Bottom"
           MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave">
        <Grid Background="LightGray">
          <StackPanel Margin="5 2 15 5">
            <TextBlock Text="View Jobs" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="13" />
            <TextBlock Text="Add New Job" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="13" />
            <TextBlock Text="Job Reports" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="13" />
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
      </Popup>
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua" 
               Foreground="DarkGray" Margin="0 5 0 0" />
  </Grid>
```

And for the back end, just close when the mouse is no longer in either control.

```
private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!JobManagementMenu.IsOpen)
        JobManagementMenu.IsOpen = true;
}

private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (JobManagement.IsMouseOver || JobManagementMenu.IsMouseOver)
        return;
    JobManagementMenu.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, bind popup to himself - wrong. Better way when bind to another control like textbox. I never see that popup use alone, it always work with other controls:

```
<TextBox x:Name="text" Text="This is a text box" />

<Style x:Key="FTC_PopupStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
    <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Slide"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>

        // other triggers
    <Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: The bindings that I have allow the popup to be "attached" to any other wpf element.  The style cleans up the code so I don't have to fully declare the popup in every location.  If the user's mouse enters the "placementTarget" of the popup, the popup opens,and the mouseover for the popup allows it to stay open when the user's mouse enters the pop-up because there are buttons inside that the user can click.  What I want is for the popup to close if the mouse is not over the PalcementTarget or the popup itself.  Right now the user has to click outside the popup to close it.